# Why does this make error when installing rethinkdb?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, make

I'm installing Rethinkdb in Lubuntu 16.04, since in Ubuntu 18.04 I could not get it, and everything worked perfectly with [the instructions my colleagues showed me](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/build/).  He did the compilation perfectly until I started building the server in the following way:

```
cd rethinkdb-2.3.6
./configure --allow-fetch
make
sudo make install
```

When I get to sudo install make I get the following error, which I do not know why it is.
If you can give me an idea of where it comes from and how to solve it ...
Thank you.

```
~/rethinkdb-2.3.6$ sudo make install
[1/9] LD build/release/rethinkdb
/rethinkdb-2.3.6/build/external/openssl_1.0.1t/lib/libssl.a(ssl_algs.o):  reference without defining the symbol'EVP_dss1@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/build.mk:334: failure in the instructions for the objective 'build/release/rethinkdb'
make[1]: *** [build/release/rethinkdb] Error 1
Makefile: 52: failure in the instructions for the 'make' objective
make: *** [make] Error 2
```

Comment: You might try installing `libssl-dev` from the repository and then reconfiguring (to avoid having to fetch and build libssl from source)